# Irreducibility conditions mod $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Does irreducibility of a polynomial over the integers imply that there is a positive integer $n$ such that the polynomial is irreducible mod $n$?

I know that $n$ cannot be prime as there polynomials irreducible over the integers which are reducible mod $p$ for every prime $p$. (This is related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459173/if-fa-1-ldots-a-k-0-whenever-a-1-ldots-a-k-are-integers-such-that-fx).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this American Mathematical Monthly article](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/281.pdf) Driver, Leonard, and Williams give examples of irreducible quartics that are reducible modulo every $n$. One such example is $x^4-72x^2+4$.  What is new in the paper is that relatively elementary tools are used. The fact that there are such polynomials was known earlier, I don't know how much earlier.